# E2276 error when attempting to export to .DLL a function overloaded across units

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, dllexport, overloading

I've been gathering useful routines into a utilities unit which I then compile into a .DLL and a .DCU, so I can choose which method is convenient to access those routines.

For instance, I've written my own **Lowcase** which acts on [wide]chars or [wide]strings to implement the obvious function, bizarrely not implemented by Embarcadero.

Similarly, I've extended **Max** and **Min** to find Max/Min of an array of numerics.

In some cases, I've essentially simply provided an alias to an existing function, such as

```delphi
function LowCase
         (const st                        : ANSIstring
         )                                : ANSIstring;
          stdcall;
begin
  result := ansilowercase(st);
end;
```

which would be exported to the DLL by

```delphi
exports LowCase
         (const st                        : ANSIstring
          ) name 'lowcaseansistr';
```

So far, so good.

I recently found that

```delphi
var
  v_uint64 : uint64;

  v_uint64 := $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  writeln('v_uint64=',inttostr(v_uint64));
  v_uint64 := $7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  writeln('v_uint64=',inttostr(v_uint64));
```

produced an incorrect result in the first instance (-1)  - in fact, wherever MSB is set, but is fine in the second case where MSB is clear.

So I found `uinttostr` and substituting this standard function for `inttostr` solved the issue.

ISTM it would be far more convenient if I could simply perform the alias trick again, so I tried (implementation)

```delphi
function inttostr
          (p_nb_int                       : uint64
          )                               : string;
          stdcall;
begin
  result := uinttostr(p_nb_int);
end;
```

(interface)

```delphi
function inttostr
          (p_nb_int                       : uint64
          )                               : string;
          overload;
          stdcall;
```

Which worked quite happily, but implementing

```delphi
exports inttostr
          (p_nb_int                       : uint64
          ) name 'uinttostr64';
```

in the project generated `E2276 Identifier 'IntToStr' cannot be exported`. E2276 seems to be related to `local directive`, apparently invoked by `local;` in the declaration - but in the source provided by EMBT in System.Sysutils.pas, the declaration is

```delphi
function IntToStr(Value: Integer): string; overload;
function IntToStr(Value: Int64): string; overload;
```

No `local;` in sight!

So - I'm stumped. How do I get around this? (XE2)

---

Here's a test program:

```delphi
program countparamsshort;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  dxutypes,
//  dxumethods,
  system.math,windows,vcl.Graphics,classes,System.SysUtils;
//{$I C:\delphi\dxu.inc}

var
  v_int64 : int64 ;           // -2^63..2^63-1
  v_uint64 : uint64;          // 0..2^64-1

procedure showv;
begin
  writeln('v_int64= ',inttostr(v_int64));
  writeln('v_uint64=',inttostr(v_uint64));
end;

begin
  writeln('min values');
  v_int64  := -214748364999;
  v_uint64 := 0;
  showv;
  writeln('max values');
  v_int64  := $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  v_uint64 := $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  showv;
  writeln('max 63-bit values');
  v_int64  := $7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  v_uint64 := $7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  showv;
//  writeln(inttostr(max(10,3)),' & ',inttostr(max([1,12,7,9,11,4])));
  writeln('procedure finished');
  readln;
end.
```

Running as-is with the .dcu *dxumethods* and include file *C:\delphi\dxu.inc* commented-out invokes the *system.math* implementation of `inttostr` with the resultant report

```
min values
v_int64= -214748364999
v_uint64=0
max values
v_int64= -1
v_uint64=-1
max 63-bit values
v_int64= 9223372036854775807
v_uint64=9223372036854775807
procedure finished
```

Which is **NOT** correct for `v_uint64`. Invoking `uinttostr` for a `uint64` would cure the problem BUT that means remembering to do so.

Removing the comment from the *dxumethods* element means that my version of `inttostr` is included - which actually executes `uinttostr`. Results are:

```
min values
v_int64= -214748364999
v_uint64=0
max values
v_int64= -1
v_uint64=18446744073709551615
max 63-bit values
v_int64= 9223372036854775807
v_uint64=9223372036854775807
10 & 12
procedure finished
```

where the value of `v_uint64` is now displayed correctly. This means that I can use `inttostr` and can forget all about `uinttostr`, so I don't have to sit here figuring out which I should use when. I've figured it out once, and now the compiler can do the work in future.

I've also un-commented-out the `MAX` call which uses the same methodology to allow me to find the `max` of an array - it means I can forget all about maxintvalue and maxvalue (it invokes those routines) but once again, I can simply use `max` - whether the traditional version or the same concept with regard to arrays. Don't clutter up the mind with three routines (and another 3 for the MIN equivalents) when one will do.

Finally, re-commenting *dxumethods* and un-commenting the include file, which contains lines like

```delphi
function inttostr
      (p_nb_int                       : uint64
      )                               : string;
      overload;
      stdcall;
      external 'dxuproject.dll' name 'uinttostr64';
```

produced identical results, this time from the .DLL - the key being to qualify the function-name when constructing the .DLL else you trip over the `E2276` error.

Now - WHY this occurs, when similar machinations around `MAX/MIN` don't faze the compiler, I'll leave to the theoreticians - and what it has to do with 'local' declarations which seem to be a Kylix hangover - well, that's in the laps (or perhaps lapse) of the gods AFAICS.

Anyhow - good outcome; problem solved. Season's Greetings...

Comment: Do you expect to use those functions from other programs written in non-Embarcadero C++ or Fortran or other languages ? If not you better use Delphi-native BPL than Delphi-agnostic DLL and solve yourself a lot of low-level compatibility gotchas. For example - you should not without special low-level measures pass strings between EXE and DLLs

Comment: "For instance, I've written my own Lowcase which acts on [wide]chars or [wide]strings to implement the obvious function, bizarrely not implemented by Embarcadero." - they are implemented in XE2. Or present a certain detailed usecase where your function works and stock function does not.

Comment: you seem to have two `IntToStr(int64)` functions - one in SysUtils and another in your own usint. Try fully-qualifed `export UnitName.FunctionName(params)` clause.

Comment: @Arioch'The: I may walk on the wild side a bit one day and program in C++, but I'll not be turning to the dark side...

Comment: @Arioch'The: There is no lowercase equivalent of `upcase`. Certainly, the lowercase-string functions are implemented. I'd just prefer to use `lowcase(something)` and have the compiler figure out from something's type quite which function to implement.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Not quite. One is the standard `inttostr(int64)`. This is a SIGNED function. My `inttostr(Uint64)` is designed for UNsigned integers. It reports `18446744073709551615` for `$FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (as would `Uinttostr64` (for some reason)). ***BUT*** your suggestion to qualify the function-name worked a treat. Make it an answer and collect your points!

Comment: I still think you have to make BPLs rather than DLLs - BPLs are native Delphi technology to consume and produce objects, strings etc. With DLL that all is fragile.

Comment: Turbo Pascal legacy UpCase(char) seems to be the only example though. And anyway, UpCase and UpperCase are not internationalized... For internationalized functionality you have http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Character.TCharacter.ToLower and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Character.ToLower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps when it comes to overloading functions and *name mangling* Delphi compiler cannot tell `Int64` from `Uint64` parameters. So try to precisely specify which function you meant to export without relying upon auto-resolving.

```
  exports UnitName.FunctionName(Params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot quite understand your overall goal. The only thing that could import such a function is Delphi code built with the same compiler as the DLL. And that code could simply call `UIntToStr` directly.

And you also seem to be re-implementing functions that the RTL already has. For instance, the `AnsiStrings` unit will supply your case switching functions for 8 bit text. And in `Math` you will find `MinValue/MaxValue` for arrays of floating point values, and `MinIntValue/MaxIntValue` for arrays of integers. It does look to me as though you are re-inventing the wheel.

That said, taking your question at face value, here is how you export the function:

```
library Project1;

uses
  SysUtils;

exports
  UIntToStr(Value: UInt64) name 'uinttostr64';

begin
end.
```

This exports the function from `SysUtils` and so uses the `register` calling convention. That's no problem to you of course since you can only call the function from Delphi.

If you are desperate to export your `IntToStr`, then you should use a fully qualified unit name. For instance, suppose the function is declared in `Unit1`, then you would write:

```
exports
  Unit1.IntToStr(Value: UInt64) name 'uinttostr64';
```

Comment: The goal is to have the function `inttostr` convert an integer to a string regardless of the argument-type it is provided with. Rather than having to remember many similar functions, one size fits all. This worked fine for `max`, so I don't have to remember the many different EMBT-supplied methodnames, I can simply use `max(value1,value2)` or `max([array of values])` and the compiler picks the routine based on data type. It also worked with a .dcu, but generated the error when called upon to produce a .DLL - and I'm using DLLs constantly - always in Delphi, though. I'm no masochist...

Comment: I don't think I can help you.